# cocos2d-x object management with multiple scenes and layers

Tags: c++, object, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I would like to understand about object management in game creation. I am working with Cocos2d-x.

I have a scene, it has several layers. Those layers are made up on several layers each.

The user adds objects to a layer via a touch event.

I am having difficulty managing everything.

Is one possible method to create a vector that contains game play layers (not layers that make up the whole game play like backgrounds) and each layer has it's own vector of what objects are on the layer and the status of each.

How then do I really effect the status of a separate layer based upon something happening in another layer.

I think I might be struggling with a combination of a good way to store what is going on in the game and making sure I can access those objects to change them.

Can a CCScene be created that then creates multiple CCScenes? and instead of swiping back and forth between various layers the user swipes back and forth between Scenes and I use the parent CCScene to know what is going on with the other CCScenes created. Or would I just create a CCNode and then create multiple CCScenes and use the Node to track what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution you're looking for is using classes more effectively.  I have a game right now where the player has to manage activity going on in 4 "hallways", each hallway made up of 3 "rows", and each row containing a variety of bad guys, good guys, and so forth.  You cycle through the hallways with a swipe and only 1 hallway is visible at each time, so each hallway is its own hudlayer.  Managing the hoardes of bad guys scattered through the hallways was a nightmare and really inefficient, so I needed a good way to split up the bad guys into groups without having a bunch of hard coded arrays in the main function....  Here's how I did it:

Inside "self" there are 4 hall hud layers, inside each hall are 3 rows which are NSMutableArrays, inside each row are a handful of arrays representing actor types (good guy, bad guy, debris, etc).

Having all of this in nested arrays can work.  Example:

```
 NSMutableArray *badGuys;
 NSMutableArray *goodGuys;
 NSMutableArray *row1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: badGuys, goodGuys];
 (repeat for row2, row3)
 NSMutableArray *hallWay1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: row1, row2, row3];
 NSMutableArray *mainGame = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: hallway1, hallway2....
```

However, this requires a LOT of explicitly defined variables.  A much cleaner way to do this would be to use classes.

RowClass.h/RowClass.m
in .h:

```
NSMutableArray *myGoodGuys;
NSMutableArray *myBadGuys;
```

then in the .m make

```
-(NSMutableArray *) returnMyGoodGuys { return myGoodGuys };
```

HallwayClass.h/HallwayClass.m

```
RowClass *myRow1 = [[RowClass init] alloc];
RowClass *myRow2 = [[RowClass init] alloc];
RowClass *myRow3 = [[RowClass init] alloc];
NSMutableArray *allMyRows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: myRow1, myRow2, myRow3];
```

in the .m:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getRowNumber : (int)rowNumber { return allMyRows[rowNumber-1]; }

HallwayClass *hall1 = [[HallwayClass init] alloc];
```

so then when you need to pull out the good guys in a certain hallway

```
NSMutableArray *hall1row1GoodGuys = [[hall1 getRowNumber:1] returnMyGoodGuys];
```

do something to the array

```
[hall1row1GoodGuys retain];
```

Alternatively if you want to handle it in a foreach loop:

```
foreach(RowClass *row in hallway1.allMyRows)
{
   do stuff
}
```

or

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
   RowClass *nextRow = hallway1.allMyRows[i];
    stuff
}
```

Defining classes terrified me for the longest time, but they're actually quite easy to work with if you don't overthink it, and do wonders for organizing stuff.

Hope you can get some ideas from some of this :3

Comment: Perfect. This is along the lines of what I was thinking about. How do you feel about the use of smart_ptrs to store the arrays, etc?